# Active class not reactive on the first load using vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, dynamic-programming

So I am building a tab component and using :class to bind the active class like this.

```
<nav class="tabs__header" >
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a
        ref="tabItems"
        v-for="(tabItem, idx) in tabs"
        :key="tabItem.idx"
        :class="{ 'b-active': idx === selectedIndex }"
        @click="changeTab(idx)">
        <span v-if="icon"> {{ tabIcon }} </span>
        {{ tabItem.name }}
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The selectedIndex is set with tabIndex value when mounted() for the first time and updated based on the 'idx' selected afterward. I have no problem with the b-active class if we click the tab manually, but it not bind the tabIndex value assigned in mounted().

This is the script I use to directly add value '0' for testing and still not get anything.

```
  props: {
   tabIndex: {
     type: String,
     default: '0'
  },

  mounted() { this.selectedIndex = this.tabIndex }
```

can anyone help me? because it seems very simple and I couldn't figure it out for 2 days

Comment: Change `tabIndex` default to `0` instead of `'0'` and `type: Number`

Comment: @Dan solved and yes it was data type problem. I changed the `idx === selectedIndex` to `idx == selectedIndex` because the `tabIndex` turns out to be a String. Thank you!

Comment: Don't write `sovled` in the title. If on of given answers solved your problem, then accept the one that describes the solution best, if you found the solution and it is not already an answer, write an answer to yourself and accept it.

Comment: @t.niese thank you, I answered it

Comment: @t.niese ok 2 more days until I can accept my own answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved and it turns out to be the data type problem, apparently `tabIndex` is a String and `selectedIndex` is a Number. 
I changed:

`:class="{ 'b-active': idx === selectedIndex }"`

to:

`:class="{ 'b-active': idx == selectedIndex }"`

and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

At initial render `idx` seems to be undefined.

Replace this:

```
:key="tabItem.idx"
```

With this:

```
:key="idx"
```

This now should work fine.

Alternatively, you may use `v-for` like:

```
v-for="tabItem in tabs"
```

Now, using `tabItem.idx` works just fine as you do in others like `tabItem.name`.

So, here's your code updated:

```
<nav class="tabs__header" >
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a
        ref="tabItems"
        v-for="tabItem in tabs"
        :key="tabItem.idx"
        :class="{ 'b-active': tabItem.idx == selectedIndex }"
        @click="changeTab(idx)">
        <span v-if="icon"> {{ tabItem.icon }} </span>
        {{ tabItem.name }}
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: See comment under question. `'0' !== 0`.

Comment: Thank you for answering and it solved and turns out was the data type problem.